# How to change in where condition to read the number from some other db table?

Tags: mysql, select

I like to change the number 2 with `id` from `users_tb`. How can I add that, `users_tb` is not in relationship with other tables it is only one column ID that is updated every time on some activity

```
SELECT messages.message,messages.sent_date, receiver_user.username, sender_user.username  FROM messages
        INNER JOIN users AS sender_user ON messages.msg_fk_user_id = sender_user.id
        INNER JOIN users AS receiver_user ON messages.receiver_id = receiver_user.id
        WHERE msg_fk_user_id = 1 AND receiver_id = 2 OR msg_fk_user_id = 2 AND receiver_id = 1
        ORDER BY `sent_date`;
```

Comment: @AlbertoMoro - Formatting improvements are always appreciated, but it's best NOT to "fix" or change the code in a "question" because it can obscure the original problem that caused the author to post here in the first place ;-)

Comment: if table is not related and data is not huge, how about splitting the query into two and doing a join at the application layer. If the data is huge in above tables, the query listed above is going to give a bad performance anyway

Comment: @Ageax thanks for the advice, I will try to be more careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT messages.message,
       messages.sent_date, 
       receiver_user.username, 
       sender_user.username  
FROM messages
INNER JOIN users AS sender_user ON messages.msg_fk_user_id = sender_user.id
INNER JOIN users AS receiver_user ON messages.receiver_id = receiver_user.id
CROSS JOIN users_tb
WHERE msg_fk_user_id = 1 
AND receiver_id = users_tb.id
OR msg_fk_user_id = users_tb.id 
AND receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY `sent_date`
```

> The cross join returns a Cartesian product of rows
>   from both tables. Unlike the INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN , the cross join
>   does not establish a relationship between the joined tables. ... In
>   general, if the first table has n rows and the second table has m
>   rows, the cross join will result in n x m rows.

I don't know the structure of the database but if you want to use the query above I think you need to insert some filter on the `users_tb` table.
Or let me know how you got the *number 2* and I'll try to help you by improving my query like:

```
...
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM users_tb ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as users_tb
...
```

Comment: Can you add some explanantion as to how this answer works and why this answer works?